# how to implement layout of hbox/vbox in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am new to Titanium. Trying to design a 'Contact US' tab for Android app using Titanium Classic.

Initialized a View for the tab.
Have filled the 1st half of screen space with Google Map, works fine.

After that i want to put -

Contact 24x7 - PhoneNumber [Call Button].

Email - email_id@mycompany.com [Email Button]

Now, i have set the layout of main view as Vertical, so that Maps and other items align vertically, which is what i want, but phone number and call button should be on the same line.

Implementing using top, left is not what i want as screen sizes vary a lot. Is there a way to implement a HBOX so that i can add label and the button in the HBox and then add them to the view.

Alternate question: How can i make the Phone number and Email ID as clickable text? so that on clicking them i can launch the dialpad or open the email app.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an HBOX you should be able to do the same as how you have created your VBOX. i.e. Create a new view with layout="horizontal" and add the label and button to this. This new view can be added to your original vertical view so that it flows as you expect.

As for your alternate question this is also possible. If you look at the autoLink property of Labels and TextAreas you will see the various options:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label

Hope that helps

Comment: I just realised that autoLink on Labels is Android only, whereas autoLink on textaareas is Android and iOS

Comment: Hi Martyn, thanks a lot. So, basically each Hbox/Vbox is a view itself with different layout. This is what i wanted to know. On the other hand, i did find about autoLink and tried it too, for email it does identify, but for phone numbers, it doesnt detect at all. How can that be done?

Comment: Yes, you can technically nest as many views as you want, but try and keep as simple as possible for the sake of memory and general readability. I haven't actually had to use the number detection but I don't see why it wouldn't work, is it maybe to do with how your number is formatted (spaces etc) or do you have an unusual number that it might not pickup on?

Comment: Hi Martin, got the point on views. On numbers front, i tried 01234567890, 0123-456-7890 , 0123 456 7890, none of them seem to work. Tried removing the starting 0 and using 10 digits, still the same.